# SpringBoot BatchConfig.java : A bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using the following code to set up Spring-Batch in my SpringBoot application

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    
    private final String[] FIELD_NAMES = new String[] {
        "ID","City","Date","Season","MatchNumber","Team1","Team2","Venue","TossWinner","TossDecision","SuperOver","WinningTeam","WonBy","Margin","method","Player_of_Match","Team1Players","Team2Players","Umpire1","Umpire2"
    }; 

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<MatchInput> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MatchInput>()
            .name("MatchItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("ipldata.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .names(FIELD_NAMES)
            .targetType(MatchInput.class)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MatchDataProcessor processor() {
        return new MatchDataProcessor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Match> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Match>()
            .sql("INSERT INTO match (id, city, date, season, team1, team2, venue, toss_winner, toss_decision, match_winner, won_by, result_margin, player_of_match, umpire1, umpire2)" 
              +  "VALUES (:id, :city, :date, :season, :team1, :team2, :venue, :tossWinner, :tossDecision, :matchWinner, :wonBy, :resultMargin, :playerOfMatch, :umpire1, :umpire2)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .beanMapped()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step1, JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return new JobBuilder("importUserJob", jobRepository)
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager,
                      FlatFileItemReader<MatchInput> reader, MatchDataProcessor processor, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Match> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
            .<MatchInput, Match> chunk(3, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }
```

But I am getting the following error on build

```
2024-01-15T18:55:47.731+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2024-01-15T18:55:47.733+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@3d182d3c
2024-01-15T18:55:47.735+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.     
2024-01-15T18:55:47.764+05:30  WARN 37756 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: HSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-01-15T18:55:48.488+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: create table match (id bigint not null, city varchar(255), date date, match_winner varchar(255), player_of_match varchar(255), result_margin varchar(255), season varchar(255), team1 varchar(255), team2 varchar(255), toss_decision varchar(255), toss_winner varchar(255), umpire1 varchar(255), umpire2 varchar(255), venue varchar(255), won_by varchar(255), primary key (id))
2024-01-15T18:55:48.562+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-15T18:55:48.683+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2024-01-15T18:55:48.712+05:30  WARN 37756 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'importUserJob' defined in class path resource [com/javaprojects/ipldashboard/data/BatchConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'importUserJob' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [com/javaprojects/ipldashboard/data/BatchConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'step1' parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}    
2024-01-15T18:55:48.714+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-15T18:55:48.783+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-01-15T18:55:48.786+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.  
2024-01-15T18:55:48.788+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-01-15T18:55:48.806+05:30  INFO 37756 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-15T18:55:48.832+05:30 ERROR 37756 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method step1 in com.javaprojects.ipldashboard.data.BatchConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' in your configuration.
```

I am trying to use an in memory database hsqldb
Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javaprojects</groupId>
    <artifactId>ipldashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ipldashboard</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As I understand this is happening because SpringBoot is not able to auto-configure the datasource bean.As I am quite new to SpringBoot, I tried to manually configure the application.properties file(which was empty in the tutorial I am following) but it resulted in the same error as above.
My application.properties file

```
# HSQLDB datasource configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand this is happening because SpringBoot is not able to auto-configure the datasource bean

The error is about a missing a transaction manager bean, rather than a datasource. Try removing `@EnableBatchProcessing` (which is not required since Spring Boot 3) and Spring Boot should auto-configure a JDBC datasource and a transaction manager that you can use in your Spring Batch job.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it is not working even after removing @EnableBatchProcessing, the same error is being displayed.

Comment: In that case, you need to define a transaction manager bean in the application context.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

Add this bean in BatchConfig class to satisfy the dependency